HighChart tooltip flicker issue of arearange chart
Here is the jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/x4k1vL02/
When hover on the area range data point, the tooltip keeps flickering.. Looks like it try to locate the arearange and line serie together... I checked the official configuration docs, if set shared: true in the tooltip attribute, the flickering issue could be resolved, but this is not what i want, i still perfer the shared: false behavior for each serie line. Could any one please help me on this?
Meanwhile, i am wondering how to change the legend symbol. For the red serie line, i would like it to have a circle shape.
Any help is much appreciated!
solve the highcharts tooltip issue

I'm afraid that this issue might be hard to resolve. But I suggest taking a look at tooltip.split option. Maybe it will meet your expectations: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/we4fm72n/ Docs: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.splite

Thank you so much Dominik. Now i use {shared: true} in my configuration.
